# Get any consecutive sequence containing the given number of elements that matches a fixed condition from a list C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a list defined as below inside a method

```
List<string> testList = new List<string>() {"A","A","B","A","A","A","B"};
```

Here my condition will be fixed say where the element matches "A". Based on upon my input, for instance  2, logic should identify two consecutive A's in the list and return them. In the above list it should return first and second elements. If my input is 3 it should return fourth,fifth and sixth elements where three A's are consecutive. If it is 4 it should not return anything. Is there a simple way of implementing this in C#

Comment: If you have multiple such sequences, should it return all or only the first sequence found?

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do what you want:

```
List<string> testList = new List<string>() {"A","A","B","A","A","A","B"};
string inputText = <your input text>;
int inputCount = <your input count>;
var zipped = testList.Zip(Enumerable.Range(0,testList.Count-1), (txt,idx) => new {txt,idx});
var result = zipped
             .Where(combined => combined.idx <= testList.Count-inputCount)
             .Where(combined => combined.txt == inputText 
                                && testList.GetRange(combined.idx, inputCount).All(z => z == inputText));
```

We zip with the ordered range [0..list count - 1] to provide indexes for your elements. Then we check if current element in the collection equals the input text, and if the first n elements starting from current one all equal input text, where n is the input count.

We can then use a foreach loop to iterate through `result` like so:

```
foreach(var r in result)
{
 testList.GetRange(r.idx,inputCount).ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
}
```

For each pattern that is found, we use `GetRange` to get the corresponding values.

Note that we are creating another `IEnumerable` object when we call Zip, and also calling `GetRange` within the `Where` clause, so I don't think this method is very efficient. Nevertheless, it will solve the issue.

Comment: What was your test case?

Comment: I used the above test case.. Kindly try it if you have time

Comment: Your edit was rejected. Can you just post the list used, pattern to search and the count in a comment instead?

Comment: List<string> testList = new List<string>() { "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B" };

Comment: string inputText = "A";
            int inputCount = 2;
            var zipped = testList.Zip(Enumerable.Range(0, testList.Count - 1), (txt, idx) => new { txt, idx });

Comment: var result = zipped
                         .Where(combined => combined.idx <= testList.Count - 1)
                         .Where(combined => combined.txt == inputText
                                            && testList.GetRange(combined.idx, inputCount).All(z => z == inputText));